# Switching between Charts with chart.js using Buttons

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am a beginner developer. I've been trying to use chartJS to get some data onto a screen. I'd like to be able to click a button that will generate another fresh set of data/axes.

I've been trying to follow other stack overflow answers but none seem to work for me... please see below.

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="forecast" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="0" type="button" >Overall (Monthly)</button>
<button id="1" type="button" >Overall (Cumulative)</button>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
        datasets: [{
        label: "DataPoint1",       
        data: [1635063, 1324343, 1880284, 1609026, 1243755, 1680117],

      }, {
        label: "DataPoint2",            
        data: [962615, 1007211, 949080, 1109982, 902847, 1059045, 1191732, 1364279, 1244704, 1392971, 1352530, 1450456],
        borderDash: [10,5],           
        type: 'line'
      }, {
        label: "DataPoint3",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(191, 63, 63, 0.9)',
        data: [1596798, 1468975, 1528036, 1612536, 1356639, 1512534, 1557276, 1609376, 1522568, 1387752, 1463280, 1562757],
        borderDash: [10,5],
        type: 'line'
      }],

},
    options: options

});
```

I'm looking to find a solution where if I click on one button it will generate a fresh new graph with a different set of data: currently the above allows me to create a combined graph of all 3 rather than separated ones. I've read that using 'destroy' achieves this goal? Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding to this documentation

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

this is what I have done, just when click happens, set the datasets then update the chart at the end

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="forecast" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="0" type="button">Overall (Monthly)</button>
<button id="1" type="button">Overall (Cumulative)</button>

<!-- Add jQuery lib here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "DataPoint1",
                data: [1635063, 1324343, 1880284, 1609026, 1243755, 1680117],

            }, {
                label: "DataPoint2",
                data: [962615, 1007211, 949080, 1109982, 902847, 1059045, 1191732, 1364279, 1244704, 1392971, 1352530, 1450456],
                borderDash: [10, 5],
                type: 'line'
            }, {
                label: "DataPoint3",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(191, 63, 63, 0.9)',
                data: [1596798, 1468975, 1528036, 1612536, 1356639, 1512534, 1557276, 1609376, 1522568, 1387752, 1463280, 1562757],
                borderDash: [10, 5],
                type: 'line'
            }],

        },
    });

    // using jQuery with es5 syntax
    $('#0').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        chart.config.data = {
            labels: ['June', 'December', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "DataPoint1",
                data: [1680117, 1324343, 1324343, 1609026, 1243755, 1609026],

            }, {
                label: "DataPoint2",
                data: [1609376, 1007211, 949080, 1109982, 1528036, 1059045, 1191732, 1059045, 1244704, 1392971, 1352530, 1450456],
                borderDash: [10, 5],
                type: 'line'
            }, {
                label: "DataPoint3",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(191, 63, 63, 0.9)',
                data: [1596798, 1356639, 1528036, 1609026, 1609376, 949080, 1557276, 1609376, 1522568, 1387752, 1463280, 1562757],
                borderDash: [10, 5],
                type: 'line'
            }],
        }
        chart.update();
    });

    // using pure js but with es6 syntax
    document.getElementById("1").addEventListener('click', () => {
        chart.config.data = {
            labels: ['June', 'December', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "DataPoint1",
                data: [1680117, 1324343, 1324343, 1609026, 1243755, 1609026],

            }, {
                label: "DataPoint2",
                data: [949080, 1007211, 949080, 1109982, 902847, 1059045, 1191732, 1059045, 1244704, 1392971, 1352530, 1450456],
                borderDash: [10, 5],
                type: 'line'
            }, {
                label: "DataPoint3",
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(191, 63, 63, 0.9)',
                data: [1596798, 1356639, 1528036, 1612536, 1609376, 1512534, 1557276, 1609376, 1522568, 1387752, 1463280, 1562757],
                borderDash: [10, 5],
                type: 'line'
            }],
        }
        chart.update();
    });
</script>
```

now load the page then click on the `Overall (Monthly)` button

Hope this helps

P.S. I am just setting new values to all three charts.  If you are thinking of having one chart at a time.  Just replace the data with one each time there is a click

Comment: Thanks a lot Dora! Dumb question, but when I use that code, button0 reacts to clicks, but button1 (Overall Cumulative) doesn't react - will I need to copy your code you added and replace (#0) with (#1)?

Comment: @MartinNguyen no worries, no question is dumb.  The other guy removed the comment but as he mentioned I was being lazy.  I used jQuery lib.  Let me edit my answer, give me a few minutes

Comment: @MartinNguyen give it a try, both buttons should work.  If the button to the left is not working, prob because of jQuery is not loaded but the button on the right should be working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! They seem to both be working :) Really appreciate it!

Comment: @MartinNguyen np, I wouldn't say mine would be the best way to do it but you mentioned you are a new developer so hope this would be easy enough for you to understand.  Personally I would at least split all the datasets into different variables and name it into something you'll easily remember so each time reading it will help you out too.

Comment: thanks a lot, my final question would be how to change the Title/Legend with your answer based on each button click? I assume it would be something like chart.config.options?

Comment: @MartinNguyen try `chart.options` without the `config`

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is supply the Chart with only the data you want the Chart to display at one time. So, if you have a couple of different views you want to toggle between, create the data for those views as separate external objects that you feed to the Chart. All `destroy` does is let you destroy some previous instantiation of Chart, so that you can always be sure you're only creating one Chart.

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="forecast" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="0" type="button" >Overall (Monthly)</button>
<button id="1" type="button" >Overall (Cumulative)</button>

<script>
// gather the monthly dataset
const monthlyData = {
    labels: ['July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
    datasets: [{
    label: "DataPoint1",       
    data: [1635063, 1324343, 1880284, 1609026, 1243755, 1680117],

  }, {
    label: "DataPoint2",            
    data: [962615, 1007211, 949080, 1109982, 902847, 1059045, 1191732, 1364279, 1244704, 1392971, 1352530, 1450456],
    borderDash: [10,5],           
    type: 'line'
  }, {
    label: "DataPoint3",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(191, 63, 63, 0.9)',
    data: [1596798, 1468975, 1528036, 1612536, 1356639, 1512534, 1557276, 1609376, 1522568, 1387752, 1463280, 1562757],
    borderDash: [10,5],
    type: 'line'
  }]
}

// gather the cumulative dataset
const cumulativeData = {
    ...
}

// define the default configuration
const defaultConfig = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: monthlyData;
    options: options
}

// create the chart with the default configuration
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, defaultConfig);

// add event listeners for the buttons
document.getElementById("0").addEventListener('click', () => {
  const chart = document.getElementById("myChart");
  chart.config.format = { monthly format };
  chart.data = monthlyData;
  chart.options = { monthly options };
  chart.update();
}

document.getElementById("1").addEventListener('click', () => {
  const chart = document.getElementById("myChart");
  chart.config.format = { cumulative format };
  chart.data= cumulativeData;
  chart.options = { cumulative options };
  chart.update();
}

</script>
```

All you need to do is add an event listener on a button (listening for a 'click' event), and then add a callback function to that listener to update the chart object using '=' and then run `chart.update()`.

Let me know if this helps!

EDIT: Even though there was another answer in JQuery, I included this one in vanilla Javascript because you may not be using JQuery. That user also included this documentation, which is very helpful: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think both your answers solved it for me: thank again!

Comment: Hey Jared, I've been building out both yourself and Dora's answers - when it gets down to the chart.config.format options, what sort of things would I be putting down there? Sorry again for the questions

Comment: Hi Martin! No worries on the questions. Regarding configuring the chart, there are plenty of options provided in the Chart.js API. Because there's so much, I can't give you a good overview of what you need to know without trying to give you a tutorial, which I don't quite have time for.

What will help you though is getting to know their documentation, found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html

That page includes an example of some of the options you might use. The sidebar has more info as well. Reading docs will improve your skills and knowledge a lot!

Comment: Thanks again, have tried to fill in the blanks with something but it's now popping up with 'Chart is not defined' - have put it into a fiddle. Not sure if you can help or point me in the right direction? The lines from line 144 downwards I'm uncertain about....

https://jsfiddle.net/martinnguyen/5218myda/2/

Comment: Hmm, oddly enough I can't get the fiddle to work even with the default Chart settings from the Chart.js documentation. There may be some issue with the fiddle environment that prevents the Chart from working properly. Try copy/pasting a basic example from the documentation (like this one: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart) into your own workspace and see if you can get it to work in your environment. Then, once you know you can get it working in its basic form, you can customize from there. This troubleshooting method always helps me when I'm learning a new library.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much to the top answer, it worked for me as well.

I have a few buttons that change the chart view, so the way to have unlimited change views would be to define the chart Element like so:

```
document.getElementById('graph').innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
```

then have your Jquery button callbacks edit the entire config, labels included like so:

```
chart.config.data = {
    labels: myLabels,
    datasets: [{
      myDataSet
    }]
  };
```

then finally update! (still inside the button call)

```
    salesChart.update();
```

full example with my the variables I'm using in my project:

```
var salesChart = new Chart(salesChartCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: areaData,
    options: areaOptions
  });

  document.getElementById('sales-statistics-legend').innerHTML = salesChart.generateLegend();
  $("#sales-statistics_switch_1").click(function () {
    salesChart.config.data = {
    labels: myData,
    datasets: [{
      data: myData,
      borderColor: infoColor,
      backgroundColor: gradientStrokeFill_1,
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  };
    salesChart.update();
  });
  $("#sales-statistics_switch_2").click(function () {
    salesChart.config.data = {
    labels: myData4,
    datasets: [{
      data: myData4,
      borderColor: infoColor,
      backgroundColor: gradientStrokeFill_1,
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  };
    salesChart.update();
  });
```